# ¿Obtener URL de imagen en Processing (JAVA)?

Tags: java, imagen, url

Cómo puedo obtener la dirección URL de las imágenes que se muestran en un visor, de una página de la cual no tengo el código php?

La página muestra distintas imágenes, con distintas urls, pero siempre en un

```
<img id="imgVisor" src="...">
```

Cómo puedo obtener, para usar en Processing, los URLs de esas imágenes?

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Cómo estás procesando las imágenes o el html en general? ¿Usas jsoup u otro framework? ¿El sitio que consultas necesita ejecutar javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo que encontré [aqui](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/foros/index.php?topic=3258.0). La clave está en `URLConnection`.

Espero que te sirva. El código no es mío pero esta fácil de entender. Solo debes de aplicarlo para que te busque y filtre las etiquetas `<img>` y el `src` creo. No recuerdo mucho de html.

```
package testurl;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Testurl {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        //se abre la conexiòn
        URL url = new URL("http://www.cambioschaco.com.py/php/chaco_cotizaciones_nuevo.php");
        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
        conexion.connect();

        //Lectura
        InputStream is = conexion.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        char[] buffer = new char[1000];
       //ACA EMPIEZA MI CONDICIÓN DESDE ACÁ PODES CAMBIAR VOS
        int leido;
        String texto = "";
        while ((leido = br.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            String datos = new String(buffer, 0, leido);
            texto += datos;
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------
        //AQUI EMPIEZA A FILTRAR EL TEXTO PARA OBTENER ETIQUETAS. PUEDES 
        //HACER LAS MODIFICACIONES DESDE ESTA PARTE. 
        //---------------------------------------------------------------
        String[] tr = texto.split("<tr");
        String fila = "";
        for (String linea : tr) {
            if (linea.contains("Dolar Americano")) {
                fila = linea;
            }
        }

        String[] td = fila.split("<td");
        String columna = "";
        for (String linea : td) {
            if (linea.contains(",00")) {
                System.out.println("---> " + linea);
                int pos1 = 0;
                int pos2 = 0;
                String cotizacion = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < linea.length(); i++) {
                    if (linea.substring(i, i + 1).equals(">")) {
                        pos1 = i;
                    } else if (linea.substring(i, i + 1).equals("<")) {
                        pos2 = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("---> " + linea.substring(pos1 + 1, pos2));
            }
        }
   //FIN DE LA CONDICION

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Testurl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Testurl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

}
```